# kindly asking how i can solve this

Tags: apt, updates, sudo, repository

```
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 10.31.1.3 8090]
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 10.31.1.3 8090]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 10.31.1.3 8090]
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 10.31.1.3 8090]
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Your issues are likely related to the network you're on; Ubuntu repositories are not local as your IP address shows;  10.31.1.3, as that is not a INTERNET addressable address (*its RESERVED for PRIVATE usage*), so your local network is no doubt restricting access via DNS, OR you have a DNS issue that needs to be resolved.  Check your local network; is it a valid network that doesn't have restrictions??  or a *policed* network such as corporate, school etc that provides invalid/local addresses for unapproved traffic etc.. OR you local DNS needs some attention...